# How Can I replace inside an array with data from outside array

Tags: jolt

I want to replace items.folderId with the corresponding name from folders.name with matching ids.
So for example I want the first item to have a folderId "DevOps" since it has the same folderId as the DevOps folder in folders.
Can someone maybe help me?

I have following problem I want to solve with Jolt transformations:

INPUT:

```
{
  "encrypted": false,
  "folders": [
    {
      "id": "c6b8ca57-3dd2-4195-884a-425a5ce96997",
      "name": "DevOps"
    }
  ],
  "items": [
    {
      "passwordHistory": null,
      "revisionDate": "2024-01-19T12:25:42.466Z",
      "creationDate": "2024-01-18T07:03:44.873Z",
      "deletedDate": null,
      "id": "82d162dd-6b64-437a-a900-801006db17b1",
      "organizationId": null,
      "folderId": "c6b8ca57-3dd2-4195-884a-425a5ce96997",
      "type": 1,
      "reprompt": 0,
      "name": "DevOps User",
      "notes": "Texas Governor",
      "favorite": false,
      "login": {
        "fido2Credentials": [],
        "username": "Greg",
        "password": "Abbott",
        "totp": null
      },
      "collectionIds": null
    },
    {
      "passwordHistory": null,
      "revisionDate": "2024-01-18T07:01:37.465Z",
      "creationDate": "2024-01-18T07:01:37.464Z",
      "deletedDate": null,
      "id": "ab4594a2-a9af-46b0-a35c-985dce838b13",
      "organizationId": null,
      "folderId": null,
      "type": 1,
      "reprompt": 0,
      "name": "rancher-credentials",
      "notes": "Texas Senator",
      "favorite": false,
      "login": {
        "fido2Credentials": [],
        "username": "Ted",
        "password": "Cruz",
        "totp": null
      },
      "collectionIds": null
    },
    {
      "passwordHistory": null,
      "revisionDate": "2024-01-19T12:26:24.243Z",
      "creationDate": "2024-01-19T12:26:24.243Z",
      "deletedDate": null,
      "id": "37781d1a-5f00-426b-a4d1-06c0fb096943",
      "organizationId": null,
      "folderId": "c6b8ca57-3dd2-4195-884a-425a5ce96997",
      "type": 1,
      "reprompt": 0,
      "name": "WildUser",
      "notes": null,
      "favorite": false,
      "login": {
        "fido2Credentials": [],
        "username": "Nancy",
        "password": "Pelosi",
        "totp": null
      },
      "collectionIds": null
    }
  ]
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "passwordHistory": null,
      "revisionDate": "2024-01-19T12:25:42.466Z",
      "creationDate": "2024-01-18T07:03:44.873Z",
      "deletedDate": null,
      "id": "82d162dd-6b64-437a-a900-801006db17b1",
      "organizationId": null,
      "folderId": "DevOps",
      "type": 1,
      "reprompt": 0,
      "name": "DevOps User",
      "notes": "Texas Governor",
      "favorite": false,
      "login": {
        "fido2Credentials": [],
        "username": "Greg",
        "password": "Abbott",
        "totp": null
      },
      "collectionIds": null
    },
    {
      "passwordHistory": null,
      "revisionDate": "2024-01-18T07:01:37.465Z",
      "creationDate": "2024-01-18T07:01:37.464Z",
      "deletedDate": null,
      "id": "ab4594a2-a9af-46b0-a35c-985dce838b13",
      "organizationId": null,
      "folderId": null,
      "type": 1,
      "reprompt": 0,
      "name": "rancher-credentials",
      "notes": "Texas Senator",
      "favorite": false,
      "login": {
        "fido2Credentials": [],
        "username": "Ted",
        "password": "Cruz",
        "totp": null
      },
      "collectionIds": null
    },
    {
      "passwordHistory": null,
      "revisionDate": "2024-01-19T12:26:24.243Z",
      "creationDate": "2024-01-19T12:26:24.243Z",
      "deletedDate": null,
      "id": "37781d1a-5f00-426b-a4d1-06c0fb096943",
      "organizationId": null,
      "folderId": "DevOps",
      "type": 1,
      "reprompt": 0,
      "name": "WildUser",
      "notes": null,
      "favorite": false,
      "login": {
        "fido2Credentials": [],
        "username": "Nancy",
        "password": "Pelosi",
        "totp": null
      },
      "collectionIds": null
    }
  ]
}
```

This was my attempt so far:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "folders": {
        "*": {
          "id": {
            "@(1,items[&1].folderId)": "[&1].folderId",
            "@(1,items[&1].name)": "[&1].folderName"
          }
        }
      },
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "folderId": {
            "*": {
              "@(3,folders[&1].id)": "[&2].folderId",
              "@(3,folders[&1].name)": "[&2].folderName"
            }
          },
          "@": "[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

It does not replace the id though :(

Is there some other way to do this? I am stuck at this part.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "folders": {
        "*": {
          "id": "folderMap.&1.name",
          "name": "folderMap.&1.name"
        }
      },
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "*": "items[&1].&",
          "folderId": "items[&1].tempFolderId"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "folderId": "=coalesce(@(1,tempFolderId),@(2,folderMap.&(tempFolderId).name))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": "items"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "tempFolderId": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hello moe,

i tried your transform rule in the https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ . It does not compile unfortunatly: 


Error running the Transform.

JOLT Chainr encountered an exception constructing Transform className:com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Modifier.Defaultr at index:1.

Unable to parse dotNotation, too many open parens '(' : root.@(2,folderMap.&(tempFolderId).name)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below spec. It should work for different scenarios alongside the input you provided.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "folders": {
        "*": {
          "name": "folders.@(1,id).folderId"
        }
      },
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "folderId": ["folders.@(1,folderId).folderId", "items[&1].folderId"],
          "$": "folders.@(1,folderId).matchingIndex",
          "*": "items[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
,
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": "&",
      "folders": {
        "*": {
          "matchingIndex": {
            "*": {
              "@(2,folderId[0])": "items[@(0)].folderId"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ,
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "folderId": "=lastElement(@(1,folderId))"
        }
      }
    }
  } /**/
]
```

Please try and let me know if I missed something.